# Continuity of $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ from continuity of $f''(x)$

Tags: calculus

If $f''(x)$ is continuous, then does this mean that $f'(x)$ is continuous and $f(x)$ is continuous?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In general even just the *existence* of $f''$ will guarantee continuity of $f'$ and hence of $f$

In general differentiability is stronger than continuity; if something admits a derivative, then is also continuos there.

The converse is not true; but if you have a Lipschitz continuos function, then you know that the function is differentiable almost everywhere. (Radamacher's theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Differentiable implies continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If the derivatives exist for all elements in the domain and not just at certain points, then yes. Otherwise we would conclude that these are are just continuous at $x$.
Note that this follows from the fact that differentiability implies continuity.